# Lightroom: Rate all images on import without losing the rating set in camera

Tags: lightroom, workflow, canon-5d-mark-iii, stars, import

I would like to rate all my images to 1 star on import in Lightroom. Not after import (Mark all, Rate, 1 Star) but rather during import.

The important thing would be not to lose the rating from the Canon 5dmkIII.

So it should rate according to the camera ratings and rate everything else 1 star on import. I know that there is no easy way to do this but I was hoping there would be any way at all as it would make my workflow way easier.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Would you be happy with a partially manual solution (i.e. click a few buttons) or does it need to be fully automated (i.e. no more clicks than current import process)?

Comment: I would prefer something automated but a partially manual solution is better than no solution. Maybe we could even automate it with a macro or similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it automatically outside of writing your own plugin and I'm actually not even 100% sure that that would do it.

For partially manual options though, use the rating filter on the previous import collection, set it to less than or equal to no stars and you will only have the unrated photos listed.  Then select them all and set the rating to 1 star.  This way you only update the photos from the previous import that didn't have a rating already.

Comment: Or a Smart Collection. I have one called 'Unrated' for example which includes all images without a rating, that way I know if anything was skipped for some reason.

Comment: Okay, looks like there is no automated solution, so this solution and the comment are closest, I guess. Thanks for your help!